# How to Pass MySQL Datetime value in URL using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to pass a MySQL Datetime value like below in a site URL which is build using Codeigniter.
So the datetime value is e.g.

```
2012-05-04 07:41:45
```

And I want it to be passed in a site URL using some king of encoding or string conversion.
As I have already tried using php urlencode() function but it is not working.

The reason to pass this in URL is because I am querying some records from database related to that Datetime. So I must pass it as an Argument to Controller and for that I must pass it under URL.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
function receiving_function($time)
{
     $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $time);  // Format this however you want the data
}


function sending_data()
{
    $date = strtotime("2012-05-04 07:41:45");
    redirect ('/yourcontroller/receiving_function/'.$date).
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a slide error in the receiving_function though, but it was not requested in the question so your answer is right :)

Comment: It should be  $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $time);
In receiving_function() :)

Comment: The `receiving_function` doesn't need the additional `strtotime`, it's already a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If your datetime is inside timestamp boundaries, you could convert it to a Unix Timestamp:

```
function mysql2timestamp($datetime){
   $val = explode(" ",$datetime);
   $date = explode("-",$val[0]);
   $time = explode(":",$val[1]);
   return mktime($time[0],$time[1],$time[2],$date[1],$date[2],$date[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `strtotime`

```
echo strtotime('2012-05-04 07:41:45');
```

Outputs:

```
1336088505
```

You could also `base64_encode` it to preserve the exact string, but I doubt that's really worth it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the exact string, I sometimes convert any non-standard url query values to hexadecimal from ASCII. On the next page, convert from hexadecimal to ASCII.

Refer to http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/code/hexstr.phps

In some situations, I find it useful when passing search query keywords as well.

Answer (score 1):

"There's an app for that!"

Codeigniter provides a handy encryption class - no main improvements over base64 but the benefit is that you get to choose the cipher you want.

Instead of passing into the URI, could you not collect from $_GET?

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');

$datetime = "2012-05-04 07:41:45";

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($datetime);

$hello_again = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_string);
```